# How to avoid global variables in functions without replacing them with class member functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# msg_process.py
#
global g_msg_mapping = {}

def process_msg_a(msg):
    global g_msg_mapping
    # update g_msg_mapping based on msg_a

def process_msg_b(msg):
    global g_msg_mapping
    # update g_msg_mapping based on msg_b

def process_msg(msg_line, msg_type):
    if msg_type == 'A':
        process_msg_a(msg_line)
    elif msg_type == 'B':
        process_msg_b(msg_line)

# main.py
# for each line in a file call msg_process.process_msg
```

Mutable global variables are not good practice in Python programming.
If I replace the above functions with class member functions, I can avoid the usage of global variables.

Question: **Is there any elegant way that I could avoid using global variables in Python functions without converting them into `class` member functions?**

Comment: Pass the objects as arguments,  return values you will need outside the function

Comment: As long as you only ever update `g_msg_mapping` in place and don't reassign it within a function, that's the way to go.

Comment: You can make them `class` instance _attributes_ and reference them with `self.some_attribute_name` (or `instance.some_attribute_name`). If you need to do some processing each time one is read and/or written, you can change them into a `property` which does require writing at least one class member function, but clients referencing the attribute don't have to be modified because of changes like this (attribute ↔ property).

Comment: I'd say that there's only one good cause to use a `global` statement: it's when you want to initialize a piece of global state in a function, e.g. lazily, and that initialization runs at most once. Otherwise, you either pass the data as a parameter, or refer to global immutable data (which does not need a declaration); it helps sanity greatly.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `dict` you want to update as an additional parameter (see below). This has the advantage that the functions can work on more generic data structures than their own class instance, but the disadvantage that there are non-obvious side effects (the update) when calling the function. This can be partially alleviated by strategic naming. For instance `process_msg_a` could be `update_map_with_msg_a`

```
# msg_process.py
#

def process_msg_a(msg, msg_map):
    # update msg_map based on msg
    msg_map[msg['foo']] = msg['bar']

def process_msg_b(msg, msg_map):
    # update msg_map based on msg_b
    msg_map[msg['baz']] = msg['qux']

def process_msg(msg_line, msg_type, msg_map):
    if msg_type == 'A':
        process_msg_a(msg_line, msg_map)
    elif msg_type == 'B':
        process_msg_b(msg_line, msg_map)

g_msg_mapping = {}
process_msg(msg_line, msg_type, g_msg_mapping)
```

Comment: Similar to Class methods, this is one of the alternative ways that I can adopt in order to remove global variables. I may be wrong here but I don't see the real values to replace the global variables in my current code which is not a library and is a standalone application.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "global" (module level) variables as long as it is understood that the module functions use it. A module and a class instance are both a namespace and you could think of a module as a singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify mutable objects without global statements.

try something like that on process_msg_a or process_msg_b:

```
g_msg_mapping[index] = 'msg'
```

In that way you're not reassigning global values (g_msg_mapping remains the same Dict), you're just modifying values from Dict.